# Is this an error? (An Introduction to the Theory of Computation by Eitan Gurari)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In this book chapter 1 (link: http://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/~gurari/theory-bk/theory-bk-onese1.html#Q2-20001-5) it says:

> Similarly, f2 is a binary representation over {0, 1} of the natural
>   numbers if it assigns to the ith natural number the set consisting of
>   the ith canonically smallest binary string. In such a case, f2(0) =
>   {e}, f2(1) = {0}, f2(2) = {1}, f2(3) = {00}, f2(4) = {01}, f2(5) =
>   {10}, f2(6) = {11}, f2(7) = {000}, f2(8) = {1000}, f2(9) = {1001}, . .
>   .

It seems to me that since f2(7) = {000}, f2(8) should equal {001} and not {1000}, going by the logic from f2(3) to f2(4). Am I missing something or is this an error?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, there was unconscious slippage into ordinary binary notation. As you observed, $f_2(8)$ should be $001$. Similarly, $f_2(9)$ should be $010$.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Do you think it's a good book for beginners btw?

Comment: I have not taken a good enough look at it to judge. Last taught a course like that quite a few years ago, am no longer familiar with the newer textboos.

Answer (score 0):

In that text, they define 'canonically smallest' as such:

"A string a is said to be canonically smaller or lexicographically smaller in $S^*$ than a string $b$, or equivalently, b is said to be canonically bigger or lexicographically bigger in $S^*$ than $a$ if either of the following two cases holds.

- $a$ is shorter than $b$.
- $a$ and $b$ are of identical length but $a$ is alphabetically smaller than
  $b$."

Since 001 is definitely shorter than 1000, it should indeed preceed 1000 in the representation.